# Add column with number of occurrencies, reset for each record

Tags: openrefine

I have records with variable number of rows and a column A with 7 possible values, all of them are repeatable.

I need a new column B based on A showing the number of occurrencies of each value per record. The count should reset in every record.

I managed to sort my rows in column A ordering them alphabetically within each record, but I can’t find the right expression to do the counting. I could only manage to obtain the total count of occurrencies of the values in A through all the data set (using text facet or facetCount).

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

If you have this...

[image]

... and want this...

[image]

... the easiest way is to switch on Jython/Python (instead of GREL) and use this formula in a "Add column based on this column" window:

```
return row.record.cells['col2'].value.count(value)
```

*Just replace **col2** by your actual column name of course*

Answer (score 0):

I found the following GREL expression on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/openrefine/c/6iQQzEx19oA) `row.record.toRowIndex-row.record.fromRowIndex`

It executes faster on larger projects.